# Magento 2 circular dependancy error on upgrade

Tags: magento2, admin-panel, cli, dependency-injection

I'm currently running a website on Magento 2.2.7

When we add any new module and run the `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` command the admin panel immediately stops working and gives us an error beginning with.

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (LogicException): Circular dependency: Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime depends on Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\ResourceModel\Stock and vice versa.

Exception #0 (LogicException): Circular dependency: Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime depends on Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\ResourceModel\Stock and vice versa.
#0 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Framewo...')
#1 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(144): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Framewo...')
#2 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(230): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, 'Magento\\Framewo...', NULL, 'dateTime', 'Magento\\Catalog...')
#3 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(34): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime('Magento\\Catalog...', Array, Array)
#4 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(59): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Magento\\Catalog...', Array, Array)
#5 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Catalog...')
#6 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(144): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Catalog...')
#7 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(230): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, 'Magento\\Catalog...', NULL, 'resource', 'Magento\\Catalog...')
#8 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(34): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime('Magento\\Catalog...', Array, Array)
#9 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(59): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Magento\\Catalog...', Array, Array)
#10 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Catalog...')
#11 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(144): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Catalog...')
#12 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(230): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, 'Magento\\Catalog...', NULL, 'stockRepository', 'Magento\\Catalog...')
#13 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(34): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime('Magento\\Catalog...', Array, Array)
#14 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(59): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Magento\\Catalog...', Array, Array)
#15 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Catalog...')
#16 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(144): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Catalog...')
#17 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(230): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, 'Magento\\Catalog...', NULL, 'stockRegistryPr...', 'Magento\\Catalog...')
#18 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(34): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime('Magento\\Catalog...', Array, Array)
#19 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(59): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Magento\\Catalog...', Array, Array)
#20 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Catalog...')
#21 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(144): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Catalog...')
#22 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(230): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, 'Magento\\Catalog...', NULL, '_stockRegistry', 'Moogento\\PickPa...')
#23 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(34): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime('Moogento\\PickPa...', Array, Array)
#24 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(59): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Moogento\\PickPa...', Array, Array)
#25 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Moogento\\PickPa...')
#26 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(144): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Moogento\\PickPa...')
#27 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(230): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, 'Moogento\\PickPa...', NULL, 'configHelper', 'Moogento\\PickPa...')
#28 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(34): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime('Moogento\\PickPa...', Array, Array)
#29 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(59): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Moogento\\PickPa...', Array, Array)
#30 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Moogento\\PickPa...')
#31 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(144): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Moogento\\PickPa...')
#32 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(230): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, 'Moogento\\PickPa...', NULL, 'generator', 'Moogento\\PickPa...')
#33 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(34): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime('Moogento\\PickPa...', Array, Array)
#34 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(59): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Moogento\\PickPa...', Array, Array)
#35 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Moogento\\PickPa...')
#36 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(144): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Moogento\\PickPa...')
#37 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(230): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, 'Moogento\\PickPa...', NULL, 'attachmentHelpe...', 'Moogento\\PickPa...')
#38 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(34): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime('Moogento\\PickPa...', Array, Array)
#39 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(59): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Moogento\\PickPa...', Array, Array)
#40 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Moogento\\PickPa...')
#41 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-user/Model/User.php(229): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Moogento\\PickPa...')
#42 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(85): Magento\User\Model\User->__wakeup()
#43 [internal function]: Magento\User\Model\User\Interceptor->__wakeup()
#44 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SessionManager.php(194): session_start()
#45 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/generated/code/Magento/Backend/Model/Session/Interceptor.php(63): Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManager->start()
#46 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SessionManager.php(130): Magento\Backend\Model\Session\Interceptor->start()
#47 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/generated/code/Magento/Backend/Model/Session/Interceptor.php(14): Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManager->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http), Object(Magento\Framework\Session\SidResolver\Proxy), Object(Magento\Backend\Model\Session\AdminConfig), Object(Magento\Framework\Session\SaveHandler), Object(Magento\Framework\Session\Validator), Object(Magento\Framework\Session\Storage), Object(Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\PhpCookieManager), Object(Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory), Object(Magento\Framework\App\State\Interceptor))
#48 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(111): Magento\Backend\Model\Session\Interceptor->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http), Object(Magento\Framework\Session\SidResolver\Proxy), Object(Magento\Backend\Model\Session\AdminConfig), Object(Magento\Framework\Session\SaveHandler), Object(Magento\Framework\Session\Validator), Object(Magento\Framework\Session\Storage), Object(Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\PhpCookieManager), Object(Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory), Object(Magento\Framework\App\State\Interceptor))
#49 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(66): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\\Backend...', Array)
#50 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Backend...')
#51 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(144): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Backend...')
#52 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(230): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, 'Magento\\Backend...', NULL, 'session', 'Magento\\Backend...')
#53 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(34): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime('Magento\\Backend...', Array, Array)
#54 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(59): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Magento\\Backend...', Array, Array)
#55 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Backend...')
#56 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(144): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Backend...')
#57 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(230): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, 'Magento\\Framewo...', NULL, 'localeResolver', 'Magento\\Framewo...')
#58 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(34): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime('Magento\\Framewo...', Array, Array)
#59 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(59): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Magento\\Framewo...', Array, Array)
#60 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Framewo...')
#61 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(144): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Framewo...')
#62 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(230): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, 'Magento\\Framewo...', NULL, 'localeDate', 'Magento\\Framewo...')
#63 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(34): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime('Magento\\Framewo...', Array, Array)
#64 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(59): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Magento\\Framewo...', Array, Array)
#65 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Framewo...')
#66 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(144): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Framewo...')
#67 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(230): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, 'Magento\\Framewo...', NULL, 'localeDate', 'Ess\\M2ePro\\Help...')
#68 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(34): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime('Ess\\M2ePro\\Help...', Array, Array)
#69 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(59): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Ess\\M2ePro\\Help...', Array, Array)
#70 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Ess\\M2ePro\\Help...')
#71 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/app/code/Ess/M2ePro/Helper/Factory.php(39): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Ess\\M2ePro\\Help...', Array)
#72 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/app/code/Ess/M2ePro/Helper/AbstractHelper.php(36): Ess\M2ePro\Helper\Factory->getObject('Data', Array)
#73 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/app/code/Ess/M2ePro/Helper/Module/Wizard.php(238): Ess\M2ePro\Helper\AbstractHelper->getHelper('Data')
#74 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/app/code/Ess/M2ePro/Helper/Module/Wizard.php(105): Ess\M2ePro\Helper\Module\Wizard->getConfigValue('installationEba...', 'status')
#75 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/app/code/Ess/M2ePro/Helper/Module/Wizard.php(83): Ess\M2ePro\Helper\Module\Wizard->getStatus('installationEba...')
#76 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/app/code/Ess/M2ePro/Helper/Module/Wizard.php(93): Ess\M2ePro\Helper\Module\Wizard->isCompleted('installationEba...')
#77 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/app/code/Ess/M2ePro/Helper/View/Ebay.php(71): Ess\M2ePro\Helper\Module\Wizard->isFinished('installationEba...')
#78 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/app/code/Ess/M2ePro/Helper/Module.php(201): Ess\M2ePro\Helper\View\Ebay->isInstallationWizardFinished()
#79 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/app/code/Ess/M2ePro/Plugin/AbstractPlugin.php(52): Ess\M2ePro\Helper\Module->isReadyToWork()
#80 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/app/code/Ess/M2ePro/Plugin/AbstractPlugin.php(33): Ess\M2ePro\Plugin\AbstractPlugin->canExecute()
#81 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/app/code/Ess/M2ePro/Plugin/HealthStatus/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController.php(42): Ess\M2ePro\Plugin\AbstractPlugin->execute('dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Array)
#82 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Ess\M2ePro\Plugin\HealthStatus\Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#83 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/app/code/Infortis/Cgen/Plugin/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController.php(32): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#84 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Infortis\Cgen\Plugin\Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#85 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#86 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#87 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#88 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#89 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(257): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()
#90 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
#91 {main}
```

I've tried running numerous other commands in the CLI such as those below:

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

php bin/magento setup:di:compile

rm -rf generated/metadata/* generated/code/* vendor/* var/cache/* var/generation/* var/view_preprocessed/* var/page_cache/* pub/static/frontend/* pub/static/adminhtml/* -R

composer update
```

But none of these resolve the error.

I'm not sure what is causing the error but it seems to happen whenever we try to install a new module and upgrade.

Comment: whatever that new module that you are adding the error says there is a problem with the code, two class having dependency with each other. to resolve it, just remove dependency of one class to the other, like DateTime should not depend on Stock or vice versa

Comment: Hi. Thanks, I'll look at that. Do you know of any instructions about modify the dependency. I don't want to break anything.

Comment: it depends on how the code was implemented. but dependency is injected in the constructor of a class.

Comment: Kindly contact with the extension developers, let's see what they say and see if this resolves the issue.

Comment: Hi. Thanks guys. Have just disabled a module called "Moogento Pickpack" and run the upgrade command again and the admin panel has functioned as expected. I'll contact the extension provider and ask them to look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who posted. Evidently this issue was caused by an extension called "Moogento Pickpack".

I contacted the extension provider and they provided a link to a troubleshooting document found [here](https://moogento.com/guides/Installing_Magento_2_Extensions_:_Troubleshooting#.22When_I_activate_a_plugin.2C_I_get_a_.27circular_dependency.27_error_in_admin.22).

However they have since released a new version of the extension and installing this seems to have resolved the issue.